# C programming: Does scanf not read values 0 and 1 as intended as integers?

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to get the sum of all the multiples of any two values.

I used `scanf` to request an integer value twice from the user.

In the code and the algorithm I created works as intended except for when the user would input value of 0 and/or 1.

I want the computer to be able to accept the value of zero and result in a total of zero and when accepting 1 a total sum of 1 but 0 gives me odd crash and 1 gives me a big value.

```
/*multiples of 3 or 5: 3,5,6,9; sum is 23*/

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int value,value2,limit = 1000;
    int i,divi,sum = 0; 

    /*read user input for the first value*/ 
    scanf("%d",&value);

    /*get sum of all multiples of value*/
    for(i = value;i < limit;){
        sum = sum + i;
        i = i + value;
    }
    printf("%d\n",sum);
    printf("done for %d\n",value);

    /*read user input for the second value*/
    scanf("%d",&value2);
    /*get sum of all multiples of value2*/
    for(i = value2;i < limit;){
        divi = i%value;
        if((divi)==0){
            i = i + value2;
        }
        else
        {
            sum = sum + i;
            i = i + value2;
        }

    }
    printf("%d\n",sum);
    printf("done for %d\n",value2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Works for me for all values except for 0 which will result in a infinite loop; i is never increased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` loop is mostly intended to count things off.  You don't need to, but it's more readable.  I'll get to that later.

For your first loop, you have:

```
for(i = value;i < limit;){
    sum = sum + i;
    i = i + value;
}
```

This...

- Sets an initial value of `i`, to `value`.  This is...a little unorthodox and might be causing you some confusion.
- Each iteration, it will test `i` against `limit`.
- Increments `sum` by the ever-increasing value of `i`.
- Increases the value of `i` by `value`.

The problem you see is that, when `value` is zero, `i` never changes.

There's also an oddity that `sum` doesn't appear to get multiples.  If `value` is `1`, `sum` will be 0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15...triangular numbers.  That doesn't sound like what you want.

Instead, I think you want to use the `for` loop for its intent, counting, and just increase the `sum` repeatedly.  Something like:

```
for(i = 0;i < limit;i++){
    sum = sum + value;
}
```

That says to add `value` to `sum`, `limit` times.

If you did need the triangular numbers, you may want to introduce a supplemental variable.  If counting isn't what you want, you might want a `while` loop, instead, for readability, something like:

```
while (sum < limit){
    sum = sum + value;  /* or whatever you need, here */
}
```

But definitely test the input `value` to make sure it's not `0`.  No matter how many zeroes you add, they're not going to be bigger than `limit`...well, unless `limit` is negative.

Comment: Thanks! You are right that zero does go in an infinite loop since the for loop would not terminate at the limit of 1000. The number 1 was also fixed.